# Integration Technique

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Which method of integration should I use to begin this problem?

$$\int_1^4\int_y^4\int_0^zz/(x^2+z^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y$$

Comment: Step 1: draw a picture to understand the shape being integrated over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

1) First draw the region of integration

2) As its presented, see if this helps

$$\int \frac{a}{a^2+x^2} dx= \arctan \Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big) + C$$

The answer is $\frac{9\pi}{8}$.